# LWC + Jest: Tracking calls to a child component's @api-decorated functions

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I struggled with this and couldn't find anything on Salesforce StackExchange or Google covering this kind of scenario in an LWC-specific context.  So I'm going to post something Q&A-style.

I have a parent LWC with a child component and button like this:

```html
<c-child></c-child>
<lightning-button label="Click me" onclick={handleClick}>
</lightning-button>
```

On button click, the parent component calls an `@api`-decorated function on the child, like this:

```js
handleClick(event) {
    this.template.querySelector("c-child").sayHello(event.target.label);
}
```

For this example, I want to write a Jest test that asserts that the child component's `@api`-decorated `sayHello` function was called with a single argument: "Click me".

I initially expected the following to work, but it failed:

```js
it("sends stuff to the child component", () => {
    const element = createElement("c-parent", {
        is: parent
    });
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    // Set up an event listener on the child
    const child = element.shadowRoot.querySelector("c-child");
    const sayHelloHandler = jest.fn();
    child.addEventListener("sayHello", sayHelloHandler);
    
    // Simulate the user clicking the lightning-button
    const button = element.shadowRoot.querySelector("lightning-button");
    button.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));

    // THIS FAILS -- sayHelloHandler shows 0 calls
    expect(sayHelloHandler).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Click me");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to introspect calls to the child component's function using `jest.spyOn()`, like this:

```js
it("sends stuff to the child component", () => {
    const element = createElement("c-parent", {
        is: parent
    });
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    // Use jest.spyOn() to track calls to the child component's function
    const child = element.shadowRoot.querySelector("c-child");
    const spy = jest.spyOn(child, "sayHello");

    // Simulate the user clicking the lightning-button
    const button = element.shadowRoot.querySelector("lightning-button");
    button.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));

    // No longer failing
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Click me");
});
```

[See Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname)